# How to get the Bootstrap 3 Datepicker to redirect to an URL when a date is picked?

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-theme

I use the Drupal bridge module **[Bootstrap Date & Time picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/bdtpicker)** with its associated JavaScript libraries.  I am trying to create a Drupal form where the user clicks on a particular month, and then the user is redirected to a page showing all the events happening that month.

This is how I build the form:

```
function rbg_date_picker($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_text',
    '#bdtpicker' => TRUE,
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m',
    '#datepicker_chain' => array(
      'my_interval_end[date]' => 'next',
     ),
     '#datepicker_options' => array(
       'viewMode' => 'months',
     ),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

The form show up and when the user clicks on a month in the widget's grid, the date field gets filled in with the year and month.  So far, so good.

However, at this point, I want the JavaScript to redirect to an URL so that I can create an ordinary page with the relevant information.  For example, if the user picked August 2017, the Javacript should redirect to "http://example.org/2017-08".

Maybe there is already support for this functionality in the Drupal bridge module (and I haven't spotted it), or maybe I need to add a small JavaScript snipped to make this work (confession: I suck at JavaScript).  Any help will be appreciated.

(PS: I know that if I add a submit button to the form, I can pick up the year and month in the submit handler.  However, I think the UX would be better if the user can just click on the month, without having to explictly hit "Submit" afterwards.)

Comment: and why don't you use ajax for that?

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian, because I don't know how to use ajax for that. Any working example will be accepted.

Comment: you want it to be redirected or you prefer to show result somewhere below your form?

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian, The result is already shown in the form. I want to be able to use PHP to process the result.With redirection, I know I can use GET to pull the data from the URL (but any alternative method to redirection/GET for getting the result to PHP will also be appreciated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect using ajax forms and ctools, first of all you will need to add #ajax property to your form field so the code will be :

```
function rbg_date_picker($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_text',
    '#bdtpicker' => TRUE,
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m',
    '#datepicker_chain' => array(
      'my_interval_end[date]' => 'next',
    ),
    '#datepicker_options' => array(
      'viewMode' => 'months',
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'SOME_FUNCTION_NAME',
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

The rest is easy, in callback function you will need to have some code like below :

```
function SOME_FUNCTION_NAME($form,$form_state) {
  $time = $form_state['values']['date']; // maybe need ['und'][0]['value']
  //Some code to fetch desired values from date like month or year
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
  //Some code to fetch desired values from form and compute 'some-valid-url'.
  $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('some-valid-url');
  print ajax_render($commands);
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Alireza Tabatabaeian, thank you for your answer, it has been accepted and upvoted.

However, your AJAX callback function does not work as it is written.  Below is how I had to tweak it to make it work:

```
/**
 * AJAX callback
 */
function SOME_FUNCTION NAME($form, $form_state) {
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
  //Some code to fetch desired values from form and compute 'some-valid-url'.
  $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('some-valid-url');
  print ajax_render($commands);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, you're right, I'll edit the answer ;)